# Regex for circular replacement

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

How would you use regex to write functions to do the following:

1. Replace lowercase 'a' with uppercase and vice versa

   - If easily extensible, do this for all letters
2. Where words are separated by whitespaces and `>` and `<` are special markers on some words, replace `>word` with `word<` and vice versa.

   - If it helps, you can restrict input such that all words must be marked one way or the other.
3. Replace postincrement (`i++;`) with preincrement (`++i;`) and vice versa. Variable names are `[a-z]+`. Input can now be assumed to be restricted to a bunch of these statements. Bonus: also do decrement.

Also interested in solutions in other flavors.

---

Note: this is *NOT* a homework question. See also my previous explorations of regex:

- [Regex split into overlapping strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437109/regex-split-into-overlapping-strings) (Alan Moore's answer is especially instructive)
- [Can you use zero-width matching regex in String split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406633/can-you-use-zero-width-matching-regex-in-string-split) (my solution exploits a known Java regex bug with regards to non-obvious length lookbehind!)

Comment: is this really an appropriate use of a regex?

Comment: I don't know. I'm trying to explore what it is and isn't for.

Comment: The first requirement is not something regex can do.

Comment: OK I made the first question simpler to just one letter. Spirit is same.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, at the risk of sounding like a pedantic jerk, no, the spirit is not really the same. You first said to replace an arbitrary letter with it's upper- or lower case equivalent (not possible with regex). Replacing single (specific) letters however, is possible. They're two different things.

Comment: @Bart: the spirit of the question is circular replacement. The text and title of the question has changed considerably since first iteration, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, ah, okay, I see what you mean. No problem, it's sometimes hard to correctly get a point across using these small comment boxes! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you no doubt have gathered, the only sensible way to do this kind of thing is to make all the replacements in one pass, generating the replacement strings dynamically based on what was matched.

Java seems to be unique among today's major languages in not providing a convenient way to do that, but it *can* be done.  You just have to use the lower-level API provided by the Matcher class.  Here's a demonstration, based on Elliott Hughes's definitive [Rewriter](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2004/07/java-implementation-of-rubys-gsub.html) class:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

/**
 * A Rewriter does a global substitution in the strings passed to its
 * 'rewrite' method. It uses the pattern supplied to its constructor, and is
 * like 'String.replaceAll' except for the fact that its replacement strings
 * are generated by invoking a method you write, rather than from another
 * string. This class is supposed to be equivalent to Ruby's 'gsub' when
 * given a block. This is the nicest syntax I've managed to come up with in
 * Java so far. It's not too bad, and might actually be preferable if you
 * want to do the same rewriting to a number of strings in the same method
 * or class. See the example 'main' for a sample of how to use this class.
 *
 * @author Elliott Hughes
 */
public abstract class Rewriter
{
  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  /**
   * Constructs a rewriter using the given regular expression; the syntax is
   * the same as for 'Pattern.compile'.
   */
  public Rewriter(String regex)
  {
    this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the
   * previous match operation.
   */
  public String group(int i)
  {
    return matcher.group(i);
  }

  /**
   * Overridden to compute a replacement for each match. Use the method
   * 'group' to access the captured groups.
   */
  public abstract String replacement();

  /**
   * Returns the result of rewriting 'original' by invoking the method
   * 'replacement' for each match of the regular expression supplied to the
   * constructor.
   */
  public String rewrite(CharSequence original)
  {
    this.matcher = pattern.matcher(original);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(original.length());
    while (matcher.find())
    {
      matcher.appendReplacement(result, "");
      result.append(replacement());
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString();
  }



  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
  {
    String str = ">Foo baR<";

    // anonymous subclass example:
    Rewriter caseSwapper = new Rewriter("[A-Za-z]")
    {
      public String replacement()
      {
        char ch0 = group(0).charAt(0);
        char ch1 = Character.isUpperCase(ch0) ?
                   Character.toLowerCase(ch0) :
                   Character.toUpperCase(ch0);
        return String.valueOf(ch1);
      }
    };
    System.out.println(caseSwapper.rewrite(str));

    // inline subclass example:
    System.out.println(new Rewriter(">(\\w+)|(\\w+)<")
    {
      public String replacement()
      {
        return group(1) != null ? group(1) + "<"
                                : ">" + group(2);
      }
    }.rewrite(str));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is using a regex for matching and a callback for replacing. E.g. in Python:

```
import re

# First example
s = 'abcDFE'
print re.sub(r'\w', lambda x: x.group().lower()
                              if x.group().isupper()
                              else x.group().upper(), s)
# OUTPUT: ABCdfe

# Second example
s = '<abc dfe> <ghe <auo pio>'
def switch(match):
  match = match.group()
  if match[0] == '<':
    return match[1:] + '>'
  else:
    return '<' + match[:-1]
print re.sub(r'<\w+|\w+>', switch, s)
# OUTPUT: abc> <dfe ghe> auo> <pio
```

Comment: I wish that Java allows callback replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Perl, also using code in the replacement:

```
$\ = $/;

### 1.
$_ = 'fooBAR';

s/\w/lc $& eq $&? uc $&: lc $&/eg;

# this isn't a regex but better (in most cases):
# tr/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/g;

print;
# FOObar

### 2.
$_ = 'foo >bar baz<';

s/>(\w+)|(\w+)</$1?"$1<":">$2"/eg;

print;
# foo bar< >baz

### 3.
$_ = 'x; ++i; i--;';

s/(--|\+\+)?\b([a-z]\w*)\b(?(1)|(--|\+\+))/$1?"$2$1":"$3$2"/eig;

print;
# x; i++; --i;
```