# How does \G work in .split?

Tags: java, regex, string, split, match

I like to do code-golfing in Java (even though Java way too verbose to be competitive), which is completing a certain challenge in as few bytes as possible. In one of my answers I had the following piece of code:

```
for(var p:"A4;B8;CU;EM;EW;E3;G6;G9;I1;L7;NZ;O0;R2;S5".split(";"))
```

Which basically loops over the 2-char Strings after we converted it into a String-array with `.split`. Someone suggested I could golf it to this instead to save 4 bytes:

```
for(var p:"A4B8CUEMEWE3G6G9I1L7NZO0R2S5".split("(?<=\\G..)"))
```

The functionality is still the same. It loops over the 2-char Strings.

However, neither of us was 100% sure how this works, hence this question.

---

**What I know:**

I know `.split("(?<= ... )")` is used to split, but keep the trailing delimiter.
There is also a way to keep a leading delimiter, or delimiter as separated item:

```
"a;b;c;d".split("(?<=;)")            // Results in ["a;", "b;", "c;", "d"]
"a;b;c;d".split("(?=;)")             // Results in ["a", ";b", ";c", ";d"]
"a;b;c;d".split("((?<=;)|(?=;))")    // Results in ["a", ";", "b", ";", "c", ";", "d"]
```

<s>I know `\G` is used to stop after a non-match is encountered.</s>
EDIT: *`\G` is used to indicate the position where the last match ended (or the start of the string for the first run).* Corrected definition thanks to *@SebastianProske*.

```
int count = 0;
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("match,");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("match,match,match,blabla,match,match,");
while(matcher.find())
  count++;
System.out.println(count); // Results in 5

count = 0;
pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\Gmatch,");
matcher = pattern.matcher("match,match,match,blabla,match,match,");
while(matcher.find())
  count++;
System.out.println(count); // Results in 3
```

---

But how does `.split("(?<=\\G..)")` work exactly when using `\G` inside the split?
And why does `.split("(?=\\G..)")` not work?

[**Here a "Try it online"-link for all code-snippets described above to see them in action.**](https://tio.run/##xVRba8IwFH73V4Q@NbgFL5sXzspQKUWwOhQRnHuIbad1tS1t6iabv71LL2O6sZtWByEhOed833dOTrKgK3q@0B/CULOo7yOVmvZzDiE3mFqmhnxGGV9WjqmjJTeJA@aZ9uz2DlEcuSE0WPvMWBInYMTlJmbZ4oJjkoCZFml4Hl37hDlJmCg0LqBZg9YQZBXkEchlUCqg1KFdhE4VumPoFaBfgsGlQHzXMpkogIAxhr2omrXWUFblkVxWKkq9XexUu@NeoV/aQhevr6TJRCEEf0vDLXsooDAFDfTDU/kIFKkGnB1almCJtpcY9HdF5TukOYHNpELi@07nGTPjiaiUaXPD4w2YrNInjxvKmOHZRHOWrmkZohC7ngmYpDFvJ9vz1KJ87BwJqdrHeYSSxpJ709ZFjBOR@fyXCcX2FGEnoT8I583479ozewBZPsFDaQg58kciHTuDqFDH5zjFXcTF4jynqNePNElrb3KbMHwF)

Comment: Is `\G` functionality clear to you or it is not either?

Comment: _I know `\G` is used to stop after a non-match_ That's not quite correct, `\G` is used to indicate the position where the last match ended (or the start of the string for the first run)

Comment: Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604177/3832970) explains what you want.

Comment: @revo I would say partially clear. I know how it works in the example I gave with the `match,match,...`, but I have no idea how it works inside the `.split`. it's also the first time I see `\G` today, so it's still fairly new for me, and probably not 100% clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm, so if I understand correctly, `\G` is normally a zero-length match, where in Java it indicates the position where the last match ended as stated by _SebastianProske_ above. But in Java inside the look-behind it matches the entire match instead of just the end, which causes these 'rules' to conflict with each other. I'm still a bit unsure why `.split("(?=\\G..)")` doesn't work though. Although I'll have to admit look-aheads/arounds/backs aren't really my expertise in general..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The problem is that this `\G` in lookbehind case belongs  to the "undefined" behaviors. It is a "miracle" it works like that in a Java regex. Thus, I would not rely on it since it does look like a bug (lookbehinds are to be non-consuming) and this can be fixed in any future Java versions. Same as `*` and `+` quantifiers in Java lookbehinds, that worked regardless of Java regex specs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I think this is reliable, because the lookbehind *is* non-consuming. The reason we progress through the string is that `split` does that, not the regex.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not delve into the code, probably you are right. However, `split("(?=\\G..)")` is supposed to work, it is again some Java quirk, compare [Java](https://ideone.com/bbyo2Q) vs. [PHP](https://ideone.com/9Isf2c), for instance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Why would a lookahead work? The example you gave there there doesn't split the string at all in Java (as I would expect). The PHP behavior seems bizarre. (It's even more bizarre with a lookbehind: https://ideone.com/S7UAmV)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If only I knew. Look, Python `re` does not split upon zero-length matches at all, [C#](http://rextester.com/MKU72549) split `12345678` with `(?=\G..)` into 2 items, `['','12345678']`, [Ruby](http://rextester.com/MIOUQ58465) splits the same way as PHP. All that indicates `\G` behavior in lookarounds is undefined, each language is free to interpret it in its own way, and I do not rely on such patterns. I am not against using them, but only by myself as "I know what I am doing".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Sorry, I meant "I think this *(the lookbehind version)* is reliable" *in Java*. Seems to work [in C#](http://rextester.com/DDIT49033) and [in Ruby](http://rextester.com/LOOZ4009) too. Not sure why you're focussing on lookaheads? But your point of caution is well-taken, particularly in light of [PHP's behavior with the lookbehind](http://rextester.com/NLOI46412).

Comment: Note: I'd expect `\G`, `(?=\G)`, and `(?<=\G)` to all behave the same, because they are all zero-width, and this is the case also in Java: [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WME3MTOvmktBoaA0KSczWaG4JLEESJXlZ6Yo5AKlNIJLijLz0qNjFRI1QcoUFIIri0tSc/XyS0v0CoBSJTl5GllAM/VKSzJz9ByLihIri/VK8iHaNJQcTZwsnENdfV3DXY3dzdwtPQ19zP2i/A2CjIJNlfSKC3IySzSUNOxtbGNi3DWj43xjlTQ1Na2B1tDOLlSraGUP0BJkO2q5av//BwA). It looks like Java is removing all empty strings from the split result, so this is a little difficult to debug, but in my example you can see all three options are the same.

Comment: Also, a little related: [Example of “use \G in negative variable-length lookbehinds to limit how far back the lookbehind goes”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27562751/7586)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> how does `.split("(?<=\\G..)")` work

`(?<=X)` is a zero-width positive lookbehind for X. `\G` is the end of the previous match (not some kind of stop instruction) or beginning of input, and of course `..` is two individual characters. So `(?<=\G..)` is a zero-width lookbehind for the end of the previous match plus two characters. Since this is `split` and we're describing a *delimiter*, making the entire thing a zero-width assertion means we only use it to identify where to break the string, not to actually consume any characters.

So let's walk through `ABCDEF`:

1. `\G` matches beginning of input, and `..` matches `AB`, so `(?<=\G..)` finds the zero-width space between `AB` and `CD` because this is a lookbehind: That is, the first point at which there is `\G..` *prior* to the regex cursor is the point between `AB` and `CD`. So split between `AB` and `CD`.
2. `\G` marks the location just after `AB` so `(?<=\G..)` finds the zero-width space between `CD` and `EF`, because as the regex cursor goes forward, that's the first place where `\G..` matches: `\G` matching the location between `AB` and `CD` and `..` matching `CD`. So split between `CD` and `EF`.
3. Same again: `\G` marks the location just after `CD` so `(?<=\G..)` finds the zero-width space between `EF` and end-of-input. So split between `EF` and end-of-input.
4. Create an array with all of the matches except the empty one at the end (because this is `split` with an implicit `length = 0` which discards empty strings at the end).

Result `{ "AB", "CD", "EF" }`.

> And why does `.split("(?=\\G..)")` not work?

Because `(?=X)` is a positive look*ahead*. The end of the previous match will never be *ahead* of the regex cursor. It can only be *behind* it.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29604177/3832970 - the point is that the lookbehind with `\G` actually *consumes* text (or at least, moves the index) in Java (although it is a non-consuming pattern).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Read through it, but didn't find it particularly clear. I'd love to see an answer with your explanation of this. You are the master, after all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The lookbehind with `\G` isn't *consuming* any text. Just marking where splits should occur.

Comment: Yeah, consuming is a complex action, `\G` here just moves the index.

Answer (score 5):

First off, `\G` definition: it's an anchor which matches beginning of string or end of previous match. It's a position. It neither does consume a character nor changes cursor position. Alan Moore previously in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761521/1020526) wrote this behavior of `\G` inside lookbehinds is engine specific. This would split at desired length in Java but doesn't produce the same result in PCRE.

So how does `\G` in `(?<=\G..)` work? Look at below step-by-step demonstration of where dot and `\G` match:

```
 ↓A4
\G..↓B8
   \G..↓CU
      \G..
       .
       .
```

`\G` matches beginning of input string then dots match `A` and `4` in order. Engine continues traversing and stop right between `8` and `C`. Here lookbehind matches:

```
A   4   B  8
     \G .  . (?<=\G..)
```

Where `\G` matches is where previous dots ended matching i.e. position right after `4` and before `B`. This process continues to the end of input string. It splits a string by 2 units of data (safely a character here). It shouldn't work on multi-line input strings and if it does it splits partially since dot `.` doesn't match a newline character or it doesn't split at all since `\G` doesn't match start of a line (only start of input string).

> And why does `.split("(?=\\G..)")` not work?

Because of a lookahead's nature - which looks forward - there is no possiblities for it to meet where previous match ended. It just continues walking, till to the end.

Comment: Great answer as well! +1. I will leave the accepted mark at _@T.J.Crowder_'s answer though, since he was faster. Both his and yours are very good answers however, and answered both my questions..

Comment: My pleasure. I didn't answer to change the acceptance mark location just tried to shine some more light on the problem.